# Genre of Kyoko Suga's "Love, Two Love"

Tags: identify-this-genre, similar-artists

What is the genre of Kyoko Suga's ["Love, Two Love"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lmwzWOuPBoA)?

I am trying to find more songs with this rhythm and arrangement style.

Can you help me figure out what songs/genres have used similar licks and brass arrangement used in the intro and throughout the song?

Comment: It's definitely a familiar sound --it reminds me of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cdvHzoOnmDI).  The beat is boogie-woogie and the instrumentation is New Orleans.   It has a bit of a rockabilly feel, but I'm sure there's a better descriptor than that.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But could you be more specific and mention the reasoning behind your thoughts? For instance, I looked up boogie-woogie songs, and I didn't see any similarity between the rhythm of this song and boogie-woogie rhythm. And what do you mean by a bit of a rockability feel?

Comment: Boogie-woogie is a shuffle rhythm (where the eight note beats are not equal length, but in pairs of long-short, long-short) typically accompanied with a distinctive blues scale baseline.  You can hear a sped-up boogie-woogie riff at the very beginning of your song, compare to this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ojwJMalbKs.  "Rockabilly" is a boogie-woogie influenced [classic country-rock subgenre](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zO6D_BAuYCI) ("Rock" + "Hillbilly")